# Can I change where the raw_input cursor is when the program is running? - python

Tags: python, cursor, raw-input

Can I change where the raw_input cursor is when the program is running?

For example, my code is:

```
print raw_input ("Please enter your last name..")
print ("                                        Type now ..")
print raw_input ("please enter your first name..")
```

I want the "Type now" part to be in the lower part of the screen somewhere but the flashing | to remain after the "please enter your last name" part.

Oooo, while I am here, can someone paste me out the code that makes my | spin around? :D or impress me with something even more fancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cross-platorm way to do this kind of "console GUI" functionality.

If you don't care about Windows, most other platforms have the `curses` module. It's a bit heavy-weight for what you want, but it can do everything you want and more.

Alternatively, if you only care about common terminals (ANSI control sequences, 80-character width, etc.), you can do it by sending explicit control sequences, or using wrapper libraries that do so on your behalf.

Or, if you *only* care about Windows, there are various different wrappers around `conio` on PyPI.

---

And as you may have guessed, the code to spin the cursor around depends on which library you used. Although you don't actually need full cursor movement functionality for that; you just need some way to read from the keyboard in raw mode. (You can do this on Windows with the `msvcrt` library, on Unix with the `tty` library and/or just using `select` on `stdin`.) Then, you just loop, waiting for a key with a timeout of, say, 0.1 seconds, and update the cursor if it times out.

Something like this:

```
cursor = itertools.repeat(r'|/-\')
while True:
    if msvcrt.khbit():
        return msvcrt.getwch()
    msvcrt.putwch('\008')
    msvcrt.putwch(next(cursor))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: I think this helps me in a way for something I will work on in the future but I am a complete beginner following a course on MIT. 
The assignments are written a rigid, commanding way so I want to play around with the questions they give me to make it more fun for me. 

I write all my code in notepad++ then load up powershell and type python MITex1.py to see the result. 

I'm not sure how to load up modules or quite frankly what they actually are. I hope to get to it soon! I copied that code into my python, but it gave a syntax error under the last ")" on the cursor = itertools.repeat ('|/-\')

Comment: First, to "load up modules" you just use the `import` statement. For example, `import itertools` and then `import msvcrt` to make the code above work (if you're on Windows, that is). Second, there was a typo in the original version of the code; a string literal with literal backslashes in it needs to be a raw string: `r'|/-\'`, not just `'|/-\'`. I've fixed that.

Comment: Also, if you're _not_ on Windows, my half-finished [`consoleio`](https://github.com/abarnert/consoleio) module gives you the same methods as `msvcrt`… but explaining how to install a third-party module to someone who doesn't yet know how to import them out of the stdlib is probably getting too far ahead.

Answer (score 0):

while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,